# Is the Director’s Cut the only PC version of "The Chronicles of Riddick: Escape from Butcher Bay"?

Tags: version-differences, riddick-escape-from-butcher-bay

A few years ago, I got a copy of *The Chronicles of Riddick: Escape from Butcher Bay* for Windows. Recently, I heard of a director’s cut of the game. I have found photos of the cover/disc including some that say *director’s cut*, some that say *developer’s cut*, and some that don’t say either.

I cannot find any information on what (if anything) is different (for the PC versions, not from the Xbox release). In fact, the research I have done seems to indicate that the director’s cut *is* the Windows version. That is, the game was originally for Xbox, then the Windows port was dubbed “director’s cut”.

Is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the PC version of the game is the Director's Cut.  The differences are covered in [this review](http://www.gamespot.com/the-chronicles-of-riddick-escape-from-butcher-bay/reviews/the-chronicles-of-riddick-escape-from-butcher-bay-developers-cut-review-6114822), in the second paragraph:

> Its visuals have been enhanced to be proportionally outstanding even when measured against the PC's extremely high standards; its controls have been optimized to make it easy to pick up by anyone who has played a PC first-person shooter lately; it features a new and exciting gameplay sequence that has been seamlessly integrated into the middle of the story; and it boasts an unlockable "commentary" mode, which annotates the entire game with extensive, often fascinating DVD-style audio commentary from the frightfully talented development team at Stockholm-based Starbreeze Studios.

Comment: That’s why I was wondering if the director’s cut is the only version for PC, because the description about commentary and the ability to steal and use a mech were already part of the unqualified copy I have. Well then I’m glad because now I don’t have to try to get another copy like I do with *Borderlands GOTY*.