# Is Assassin’s Creed in the Ultimate Collection the Director’s Cut?

Tags: version-differences, assassins-creed

I am considering buying a copy of the *Assassin’s Creed Ultimate Collection* but am having trouble determining if the copy of *AC1* in it is the Director’s Cut or not.

(If not, is there an update or something to convert the normal version to the director’s cut?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If random forum posts are to be trusted, then [someone here](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/659936-Question-about-Assassin-s-Creed-quot-Ultimate-Collection-quot-Forums) claims that it is.

Also, Google searches are leaning in the same direction, so i'm going to go with yes.

Comment: That’s what I figured too. I guess it is like *Chronicles of Riddick - Escape from Butcher Bay*; the [only PC version is the Director’s Cut](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37763/).

Comment: While the link might answer the question, if it dies, this answer becomes useless. Please provide the needed information for the answer to be useful even if the link dies.